# Creating Object In JavaScript Without Function Use

Tags: javascript

What Is The Best Way To Create An Object In JavaScript Without Function Use...

Not Like:

```
function functionName(){
  this.propertyname1 = value1;
  this.propertynameN = valueN;    
}

objName = new functionName();
objName.propertyname1;    //value1
```

Comment: Do you want multiple instances of `functionName` ?

Comment: Object.create({propertyname1:'', propertynameN:''}); or 
objName = {propertyname1:'', propertynameN:''}

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

`objName = {property1: "value"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var objectname = {property: "value"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code creates an object, and uses `functionName.prototype` as the prototype of the new object.

If you want to create an object *with a prototype*, but don't want to use a *constructor function*, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```
var myPrototype = {
    propertyname1: value1,
    propertynameN: valueN
}
objName = Object.create(myPrototype);
```

If you don't need the ability to make multiple objects with the same prototype, an object literal will do just fine:

```
var objName = {
    propertyname1: value1,
    propertynameN: valueN
}
```